# Getting the second item after using str_split() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data frame that contains some questions.  I want to drop the leading number and period from the question, but leave everything else. I don't really understand regex, but this seems like a perfect use for `str_split()`, specifically within a `dplyr` pipeline.  However, after splitting the string, I'm not sure how to grab the the second item.  I tried accessing it by position, and that didn't work.

```
x <- structure(list(question = c("01. I like my job.", 
                                 "02. I like my house.", 
                                 "03. I like my car.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

x %>% 
  mutate(words = str_split(question, "."))
```

Returns this:

```
question                        words
01. I like my job.         <chr [19]>           
02. I like my house.       <chr [21]>           
03. I like my car.         <chr [19]>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
question                             words
01. I like my job.         I like my job.           
02. I like my house.       I like my house.     
03. I like my car.         I like my car.
```

I've also tried using `separate()` and `strsplit()` but I couldn't make any of those work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think  you're looking for `str_replace` (or `sub` in base R)

```
x %>% mutate(words = str_replace(question, "^\\d+\\.", ""))
#              question             words
#1   01. I like my job.    I like my job.
#2 02. I like my house.  I like my house.
#3   03. I like my car.    I like my car.
```

Explanation:

1. `^` is the left string anchor
2. `\\d+\\.` matches one or more digit(s) followed by a full stop

You *can* use `str_split` in the following way

```
x %>% mutate(words = paste0(map_chr(str_split(question, "\\."), 2), "."))
```

giving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the pattern to be `\\.`, and then get the second element for the `word` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>% 
  mutate(words = str_split(question, "\\. ")[[1]][[2]]) 
#               question          words
# 1   01. I like my job. I like my job.
# 2 02. I like my house. I like my job.
# 3   03. I like my car. I like my job.
```